# Resizing issue when old projects opened in Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have a project which is implemented in xcode10 which is in autoresizing, but as per the apple guidelines have to submit the app through xcode11 from april onwards. I have opened the project in xcode11 but the UI seems disturbed, Even if I change the UI, its reverting back again(disturbed),  if I close and opened the project in xcode11 again.
please find the screen shot of view controller in storyboard[image]

Comment: are you using Storyboard to build UI or doing it programmatically ?

Comment: I am using storyboard for UI, not doing programatically

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your storyboard to question?

Comment: Please check the screenshot above